# Remove all media formatters accept my own in MVC5 + WebAPI

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.1, mediatypeformatter

I have a question, I think it's a little vague but forgive me if it is.

I have custom `MediaTypeFormatter` that I want to use, but here is the question if I remove all the others formatters would it `improve my preformance`?

If not I would like to know why also if it is....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the HTTP request arrives, WebAPI will look up each formatter's `SupportedMediaTypes` to get formatter appropriate for the request's `Accept-Type`. Removing formatters will make look up quicker, but cost of the lookup is very tiny comparing to the serialisation/deserialisation itself and other processes. However, one merit I found out is that by removing all formatters but one we use, we make sure that client will always get our chosen format. By default formatters, clients can choose either `Accept: application/json` or `Accept: text/xml`, which might not be something we want e.g. we may not want to support XML at all.

Comment: I don't understand your answer can you extend please?